# Ruby On Rails: Render Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to show a specific image on the first iteration when the partial template is called, but not the rest:

```
view file:

<% @categories.each do |category,i,category_locales| %>
    <div class="featured_deals">
        <%= render :partial => "medium_deal", :collection => category_locales, :as => :deal_locale %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

medium_deal file:

```
<% deal = deal_locale.deal %>

<%= image_tag 'layout/featured_deal_left_blue.png', :style => 'float: left; padding-top: 11px;' %> 
# I only want this image to show for the FIRST element of category_locales, but not the rest.

<div class="featured_deal_wrapper">
        Hello     
</div>
```

I tried passing a counter in the first view file, but it is not incremented until the "each" passes through again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
<% if deal_locale_counter == 0 %>
  <%= image_tag 'layout/featured_deal_left_blue.png', :style => 'float: left; padding-top: 11px;' %> 
<% end %>
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables